# c# Dataset - modify SELECT statement with WHERE conditions

Tags: c#, .net, datasource

I have a dataset, tableadapter, and bindingsource for getting data out of a database and into a windows form.

The `SELECT` statement is basically a `SELECT * FROM Employee`s
which returns 50,000 rows.

I want to add a `WHERE` clause before I fill it, so I am not populating the datatable with 50,000 rows.  For example, modify the `SELECT` statement to:

```
SELECT * FROM Employees WHERE Lastname LIKE 'A%'
```

How can I do this?

For example I am trying this but the SelectCommand is set to nothing, so it fails.  Not sure when the SelectCommand gets populated.

```
Me.taBoxesCarrierTech.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = 
Me.taBoxesCarrierTech.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText & _
"AND BL.LOG_NO = " & mPhantomLogNum
```

Comment: Are you aware how basic string manipulation works in C#?

Comment: Yes but where do I modify the select command?  I am trying things like: Me.taBoxesCarrierTech.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = Me.taBoxesCarrierTech.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText & _
            "AND BL.LOG_NO = " & mPhantomLogNum  but the CommandText is set to Nothing

Comment: How do you query your DB? Are you using stored procedures? If so, I would recommend using a parameter to avoid sql injections.

Comment: I have a design time DataSet created that has direct SQL, but I basically want to modify the SQL in runtime.

Comment: is CommandText necessary?  I don't think so.  There is an answer posted and accept if all right.

Comment: I would like to say one thing about using where conditions and hard coded queries here.  Please do not hard code sql queries in the application logic or on the data layer. Parameterize your queries and wrap it up with a stored procedure. [OWASP][https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Main_Page] suggests using [strongly typed parameterized queries][https://www.owasp.org/images/0/08/OWASP_SCP_Quick_Reference_Guide_v2.pdf].  See Database Security section in the pdf document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use a WHERE clause with a TableAdapter, you need a to build a [parameterized TableAdapter query](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171905.aspx)

Comment: Yes, thanks.  That's the solution.  At design time modify the SELECT statement to have ... WHERE Lastname = :Lastname (this is an oracle db).  Then add a parameter using Source as LastName.  Then in the FILL command pass it as a parameter   TableAdapter1.Fill(Me.DS_Something.dtDataTable, "Smirth")